# Problem with uiscrollview setcontentoffset animated not scrolling when animated:yes is set

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, animated

This is very odd and I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts?

I'm trying to scroll a UIScrollView in response to a button press on the iPad.

If I do:

```
CGPoint currentOff = scrollView.contentOffset;
currentOff.x+=240;
[scrollView setContentOffset:currentOff animated: NO];
```

The scroll view jumps to the required position as expected, but I want it to scroll. However, when I do:

```
CGPoint currentOff = scrollView.contentOffset;
currentOff.x+=240;
[scrollView setContentOffset:currentOff animated: YES];
```

Then it doesn't do anything! I have another scroll view which is working properly and responds to `setContentOffset:YES` as expected, so I am quite puzzled. Any ideas on why scrolling might not happen are most welcome!

Also, `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender`  is not receiving anything at all when `animated:YES` is used but is invoked when `animated:NO` is used!

Comment: hm, i'm seeing something very similar. both setContentOffset and scrollRectToVisible work as expected with animated = false, but do nothing with animated = true. also curious, if i drag the scrollView with my finger a bit and then try the button again, it works. i've printed the scrollView's contentSize and it looks correct.

Comment: Funny, I just had the same issue, but reversed. It only works if I animate it.

Comment: Hi. check out my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27088865/1510171

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I had this happen too and ended up doing this workaround:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = ...;
}];
```

Comment: can you explain what might be the reason (for setContentOffset:animated: not working and doing this way working)

Comment: I'm  not sure, I think it's a bug that the animated version doesn't work.

Comment: I tried aepryus' suggestion of eliminating multiple setContentOffset: calls, but I didn't find any redundant calls to eliminate.  This solution worked for me - thanks!

Comment: It is working indeed. But still don't understand the reason for this.

Answer (score 10):

Speaking from personal experience, this problem occurs when setContentOffset: is getting called multiple times before the animation has had a chance to run.

I haven't totally tracked down the issue, but I believe the problem goes something like this:

setContentOffset:animated gets called which sets the new offset value.
setContentOffset: subsequently gets called with the same parameters, which cancels the animation.  It also notices that the new parameters are the same as the old parameters so assumes nothing needs to be done, even though the animation hasn't run yet.

The solution above somehow breaks this cycle, but perhaps a less kludgy solution is to put break points in the code and eliminate the multiple calls.

Comment: This explanation helped me in a similar issue.  Thanks!

Comment: My fix was to remove a call to `setNeedsLayout` after `setContentOffset:animated`.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say with that piece of code you gave. And in fact, if you're saying, that you have a project, where everything is working under the same conditions, then obviously the conditions aren't the same :) I couldn't reproduce the issue, but here are some assumptions for 2 cases:

1. Creation of UIScrollView with nib.

   - Just don't forget to create IBOutlet and to bound it to the scrollView element in nib. In a simple view based application just after that I got scrollView working as you wished in animated: both YES and NO. But to make work

   `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender;` you must set the delegate:

`yourScrollView.delegate = self;`

where 'self' is class, where you have your scrollViewDidScroll function; btw this class must conform to the 'UIScrollViewDelegate' protocol.

2.Creation of UIScrollView object manually.

- here the idea is basically the same, so I'll just provide some simple code:

  ```
  -(void) creatingScrollView {
      UIScrollView *newScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 280, 44)];
      newScroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
      newScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
      newScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

      // ... some subviews being added to our scroll view

      newScroll.delegate = self;
      [self.view addSubview:newScroll];
      [newScroll release];
  }
  ```

This works for me. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with tableviews, as [aepryus solution's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16898199/3803038) says: **setContentOffset: is getting called concurrently with other animations**.

In my case I've just invert this commands:

```
[tableView reloadData];
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(240, 0) animated:FALSE];
```

like this

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(240, 0) animated:FALSE];
[tableView reloadData];
```

The animation start after the content offset has changed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem wiehre the ScrollView doesn't scroll.

Then I disabled "Use Auto Layout" on the view, and after that the ScrollView works.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Xamarin.iOS

```
InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
  scrollView.SetContentOffset(new PointF((page * UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width), 0), true);
});
```

This can also be solved using `UIView.Animate`

```
UIView.Animate(
    duration: .25,
    animation: () =>
    {
       scrollView.SetContentOffset(new PointF((value * UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width), 0), true);
    }
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `animated` be *false* when you use a custom animation (`UIView.Animate`)?

Answer (score 1):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.10, animations: { () -> Void in

            let loginScrollViewCurrentPosition:CGPoint = CGPointMake(self.loginScrollView.contentOffset.x, self.loginScrollView.contentOffset.y) as CGPoint
            self.loginScrollView.setContentOffset(loginScrollViewCurrentPosition, animated: true)

            })
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case I was also intercepting:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {...}
```

This method is called immediately after: 
(It doesn't wait until the end of the animation):

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:currentOff animated: YES];
```

Which means that if you have got any logic that "waits" the end of the animation and you intercept scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation then the result will be undefined, IE: ending the animation prematurely.

EDIT: The accepted solution/workaround:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = ...;
}];
```

Also "works" in my scenario because setting the contentOffset directly doesn't invoke scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation

Answer (score -2):

You could try:

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(240, 0) animated:YES];
```