# UIScrollView strange behavior on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios-simulator, device

I have implemented a 'UIScrollView' in my application, like this :

```
scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(59.0, 116, 180, 145)];
[scroller setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[scroller setPagingEnabled:NO];
[scroller setScrollEnabled:NO];
[scroller setDelegate:self];
if (![scroller isDescendantOfView:MyUIView])
{
    [MyUIView addSubview:scroller];
}
```

To scroll, I add a 'UIButton' which do :

```
Y = Y + 200;
[scroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(Y, 0) animated:YES];
NSLog(@"Scroll : %f", scroller.contentOffset.x);
```

On the 'simulator', this works ! But on the device, the scroller.contentoffset.x gives me some random values and so move my content really strangely… The simulator and my device are in 'release' mode

I don't really understand why this doesn't works because in a precedent app, it was working perfectly.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT :

When doing :

```
[scroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(Y, 0) animated:NO];
```

it works correctly

When doing :

```
[scroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(Y, 0) animated:YES];
```

it gives me random values, and do some wrong things

Comment: What is `Y`? Where is the value initialised?

Comment: Are you sure Y is inside the scroller's contentSize ?

Comment: Y is an int value, which is initialized into the viewdidload method. But the nslog gives me really low values, like 10, or 30...

Answer (score 1):

Try Scroll rect to visible method instead

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Pass the rect of your interest. Also make sure that you have set the contentSize of your scrollview.

Comment: What is 'MyUIView' shouldn't it be 'self.view' or something?

Comment: It works, but this make the same behavior than the other function, scroll with variable values, not as on the simulator… Check the edit

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it looks to be a bug. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941315/problem-with-uiscrollview-setcontentoffset-animated-not-scrolling-when-animated) is the solution.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
self.scrollView.contentOffset = ...;
}];
```